# Targeting table rows with jQuery where <td> contains value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

If I have a table containing `<tr class="foo">` with `<td class="data">` that contains the word Yes or No, such as:

`<tr class="foo"><td class="data">Yes</td></tr>`

or

`<tr class="foo"><td class="data">No</td></tr>`

Is there any way with jQuery to change the class of `<tr>` to `<tr class="bar">` for only those rows  where `<td class="data">` has Yes in it?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Just one loop, value comparison and setting class?

```js
$('td.data').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.text() === 'Yes') {
    $this.parent().removeClass('foo').addClass('bar');
  }
})
```

```css
.foo td {background: red}
.bar td {background: green}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="foo"><td class="data">Yes</td></tr>
  <tr class="foo"><td class="data">No</td></tr>
  <tr class="foo"><td class="data">No</td></tr>
  <tr class="foo"><td class="data">Yes</td></tr>
  <tr class="foo"><td class="data">No</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks so much!